# Skinning matrices scales mesh unexpectedly

Tags: opengl, skinning

I have a 3d model of vectors, I am applying a series of weighted transformation matrices according the Collada spec and that animates the model. The animation works great but the model is being scaled even though I've verified that the scaling information in the matrices are all at identity and that weights all add up 1.0. I've also verified that I am not applying the projection matrix twice during skinning.

Finally, I verified that when I bypass the skinning code the model is scaled properly.

So: is there anything obvious as to what could cause the model to scaled (~0.5)?

here's the relevant shader code:

```
vec3 pos = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
{
    float weight = weights[j];
    pos += (jointMats[j] * (jointInvMats[j] * inpos)) * weight;
}
```

[EDIT] code changed to reflect proper matrix/vertex multiplication thanks to Christian and Andreas in comments below. However, the original problem persists.

Comment: um, wait, in seems I'm not supposed to initialize the pos variable with all 0's but with the original vector I'm animating....?

Comment: *"um, wait, in seems I'm not supposed to initialize the pos variable with all 0's but with the original vector I'm animating....?"* - No, you want a sum, therefore start with `0`! But it seems your matrix multiplication order is messed up. You trasform your vertex into the reference pose by multiplying the inverse of the rest pose matrix from the left, but then you transform it into the current pose by multiplying the current pose matrix from the right. Doesn't make sense, except if one of the matrices is column major and the other row major, which would be quite weird.

Comment: So the fix is to use `pos += (jointMats[j] * (jointInvMats[j] * inpos)) * weight` then?

Comment: yes, that was definitely an issue and your snippet is the proper order - keeping the vector to the right of the matrices. It also explains other things wrong with my Collada importing (the matrix is considered column-major "mathematically" but stored as row-major in the .xml for "readability" - until Christian pointed out the messed up multiplication I didn't fully understand what that meant in the documentation. Now it's clear to me that every 4x4 matrix I read from the .xml needs to be transposed during read for GLKit and OpenGL - THANKS! Christian).

Comment: HOWEVER: I still have the scaling issue UNLESS I initialize the `pos` with the original vector (`inpos` in the code snippet) and add the transformed versions to that so I'm still confused.

Comment: @pablo No, you shouldn't do that. Initializing it with `0` was already correct. Think about it, you want to blend together all the points transformed by the individual matrices, the untransformed point doesn't belong into this blend. Just always make sure the weights sum to 1 for each vertex, otherwise you will of course get mismatching scales.